# LIN bus slave transmitting without master

Tags: bus

How does a LIN bus slave device behave, if no master is connected?

In my research I noticed, that in LIN version 2.0 every message is initialised by a header frame which is sent by the master device.
For tests I powered a LIN slave device and did not connect any master to the bus. Then I measured the voltage on the LIN bus line with an oscilloscope. And it seems that the slave device is transmitting data.

How can this be explained?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to decode the frames? Do they have the break period? sync byte? id? Possibly this is a master, not a slave.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible, i mean a slave cannot start the communication. 
The master has to send first a Header:
- Sync Break Field (14 Tbit)
- Sync Field  (0x55)
- ID field
...and when one slave in the bus detects that this request is for him, then replies, otherwise it ignores the received header.

Answer (score 0):

SLAVE can not transmit data if it does not get ID published by the master. Master must say first ID x please reply, then slave will reply. Otherwise your slave may be designed to keep on answering without request causing collision.